# child_of not working in wp_dropdown_categories

Tags: taxonomy

I have `wp_dropdown_categories` working without setting `child_of`. Once I set `child_of`, all categories disappear. Here's my code, what should I do to enable `child_of`?

```
function dropdown(){
    $book_term=term_exists('book','category');
    $book_term_id = $book_term['term_id']; 
    $dropdown = array(
    'child_of'   => $book_term_id,
    'hide_empty' => 0
    )
?>
    wp_dropdown_categories( $dropdown );
<?php
}
```

Comment: Where is $book_term_id defined?

Comment: inside this function, $book_term=term_exists('book','category'); $book_term_id = $book_term['term_id']; I tried var_dump, the id is correct.

Comment: You have the call to the function outside the PHP context and you're missing a trailing semicolon `;` after the function. Please turn `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` on in your `wp-config.php` file and tell us about the error output.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `$book_term_id` has not been set. You either need to pass it to your function or set it in your function.

Pass it to your function:

```
<?php dropdown($book_term_id); ?>
```

Set it in your function:

```
function dropdown(){
  $book_term_id = 5; // if a global variable, you can just use:  global $book_term_id;  
  $dropdown = array(
    'child_of'   => $book_term_id,
    'hide_empty' => 0
  )
  wp_dropdown_categories( $dropdown );
}
```

Comment: sorry, I just edited my question. I have the book_term_id defined inside the funtion. Initially I didn't paste it here just for simplify things.

Comment: Ok. I see you've updated your code. Are you getting the term id properly? See updated code above.

Comment: I think I get the id correctly. I tried var_dump, it returns the id number. So, my $book_term_id is the same as using the id number.

Comment: What did you do var_dump on? On `$book_term_id`? If not, do an echo on `$book_term_id` and see what it returns. (I assume there are child categories.)

Comment: either var_dump or echo $book_term_id returns number of 56. this 56 is the top level term, it has children, but not grandchildren. $book_term->term_id doesn't work, echo or var_dump $book_term->term_id got no result.

Comment: Why is `wp_dropdown_categories` outside of **php** tags? I've updated my code.

Comment: just find out what's wrong-- the children is empty by get_term_children( $book_term_id, 'category' ); but at backend, I can see all the children listed under the parent

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is THE problem, but there are problems. your PHP (WP) function is outside of PHP:

```
?>
    wp_dropdown_categories( $dropdown );
<?php
```

so it'll print as text, not execute.

also, when you put it w/in PHP, make sure to add a semi-colon after the array's closing parenthesis:

```
  $dropdown = array(
    'child_of'   => $book_term_id,
    'hide_empty' => 0
  );
  wp_dropdown_categories( $dropdown );
}
```